# How to use $.Post Ajax Request to add in a list where there is a field of type person or group? I keep on receiving bad request (Sharepoint)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, sharepoint

How to use $.Post Ajax Request to add in a list where there is a field of type person or group? I keep on receiving bad request (Sharepoint). Here is the code:

```
function addHappinessKeyRecord(keyName, keyMessage, quarterName, year, employeeGivenToName) {
  var url = "http://nvdsh2016ogero:777//_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Happiness Key Records')/items";
  var happinessKeyObject = {
    '__metadata': {
      'type': 'SP.Data.HappinessKeyRecordsListItem'
    },
    'Title': keyName,
    'EmployeePersonId': _spPageContextInfo.userId,
    'EmployeePersonGivenToId': _spPageContextInfo.userId,
    'Message': keyMessage,
    'Quarter': quarterName,
    'Year': year
  };
  postOrUpdateAjaxRequest(url, "POST", JSON.stringify(happinessKeyObject), function() {
    console.log(dataPostStatus);
  });
}
```

Comment: What does the 400 error say? Can you show me the field definition for `EmployeePersonId` and `EmployeePersonGivenToId`? (Update the question please :))

Comment: Oh and show us your `postOrUpdateAjaxRequest` code please.

Comment: Also, make sure you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json;odata=verbose`

Comment: Solved ! Thanks